# play 2.0.2 test query parameter error

Tags: java, routes, playframework-2.0

I have a Java play 2 controller which accept query string parameter like this:

Controller:

```
public static Result syncInterests(
        String lastsyncdate,
        String fooid) {
}
```

Test:

```
Result result = routeAndCall(fakeRequest(GET, "/foo/sync?fooid=123"));
```

But getting this error. What does it mean? This is a java action for sure.

```
failed: This is not a JavaAction and can't be invoked this way.
```

EDIT:

This is how I define in routes. lastsyncdate is optional.

```
GET  /foo/sync  controllers.FooSync.syncInterests(lastsyncdate: String, fooid: String)
```

EDIT:

I could not get this to work. So I use this function to test to continue my other works.

```
Result result = callAction(controllers.routes.ref.FooSync.syncInterests(time, fooId));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your url "/foo/sync?fooid=123" is incorrect for the controller.  It should be     **"/foo/syncInterests?fooid=123"**   and **syncInterests**  method should have return statement.

Comment: Ok. Then try to test with return statement.

Comment: it is still not working even I make a simple return. So I end up using this. Result result = callAction(controllers.routes.ref.FooSync.syncInterests(time, fooId));